# Redeem girft card for child

Tags: google-play-store

My child got a tablet for christmas and a google play card. I set her up on the under 13 age google acct, but when i try to add her card it keeps popping up an error - `orafi01`

Comment: Which is your country? In India under 13 cannot be ,[added for gift cards](https://play.google.com/about/card-terms.html). Similar restrictions for you?

Comment: I have it as united states

Comment: In which case, it may be easier to add it family account as [explained here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/forum/AAAA8CVOtD8YfkxXllxi4c/?hl=en) and buy it from that account

Comment: Instructions for family account https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7007852?hl=en